# How to parse the json data in C#/VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I get the json data in string:

I get error unable to convert array to classname

My json and the classes created are [Code what i have done](http://paste2.org/EzgKpVc3)

On button click i have tried this.I unable to figure out how to do it

```
Dim inputUrl As String


Dim output As String
        TryExecute(Sub()
                       ' Using client = New WebClient()
                       city = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(If(city, String.Empty))
                       state = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(If(state, String.Empty))
                       zipcode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(If(zipcode, String.Empty))
                       street = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(If(street, String.Empty))

                       inputUrl = String.Format(Url, AuthId, AuthToken) + String.Format(QueryString, street, city, state, zipcode)

                       ' myProducts(List < Product >= New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize < List < Project >> (objUSPSAPI.FormatJson(client.DownloadString(url__1))))
                       output = objUSPSAPI.FormatJson(wsClient.DownloadString(inputUrl))
                       Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer
                       Dim result = jss.Deserialize(Of components)(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i did it!

Json data:

```
[
    {
        "input_index": 0,
        "candidate_index": 0,
        "delivery_line_1": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy",
        "last_line": "Mountain View CA 94043-1351",
        "delivery_point_barcode": "940431351000",
        "components": {
            "primary_number": "1600",
            "street_name": "Amphitheatre",
            "street_suffix": "Pkwy",
            "city_name": "Mountain View",
            "state_abbreviation": "CA",
            "zipcode": "94043",
            "plus4_code": "1351",
            "delivery_point": "00",
            "delivery_point_check_digit": "0"
        },
        "metadata": {
            "record_type": "S",
            "zip_type": "Standard",
            "county_fips": "06085",
            "county_name": "Santa Clara",
            "carrier_route": "C909",
            "congressional_district": "18",
            "rdi": "Commercial",
            "elot_sequence": "0089",
            "elot_sort": "A",
            "latitude": 37.42202,
            "longitude": -122.08433,
            "precision": "Zip9",
            "time_zone": "Pacific",
            "utc_offset": -8.0,
            "dst": true
        },
        "analysis": {
            "dpv_match_code": "Y",
            "dpv_footnotes": "AABB",
            "dpv_cmra": "N",
            "dpv_vacant": "N",
            "active": "Y",
            "footnotes": "N#"
        }
    }
]
```

**Add these references**

1) ADD these references

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
```

**Create the classes to support the json data**
1)Create Classes to support json
2) Note the attributes used for class `<DataContract()>` and datatype `<DataMember()>`
3)The name of the property should be same as that in the json data

```
<DataContract()>   'class attribute
    Public Class JsonData

        Private _input_index As String
        <DataMember()>                     'datatype attribute
        Public Property input_index As String  'name of  property same as Json
            Get
                Return _input_index
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _input_index = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _candidate_index As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property candidate_index As String
            Get
                Return _candidate_index
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _candidate_index = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _delivery_line_1 As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property delivery_line_1 As String
            Get
                Return _delivery_line_1
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _delivery_line_1 = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _last_line As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property last_line As String
            Get
                Return _last_line
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _last_line = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _delivery_point_barcode As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property delivery_point_barcode As String
            Get
                Return _delivery_point_barcode
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _delivery_point_barcode = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _Componentlist As components    'the class of this list is down 
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property components As components    ' note here: name is same same as in json 
            Get
                Return _Componentlist
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As components)
                _Componentlist = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _metadatalist As metadata  'the class of this list is down
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property metadata As metadata
            Get
                Return _metadatalist
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As metadata)
                _metadatalist = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _anslysislist As analysis  'the class of this list is down
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property analysis As analysis
            Get
                Return _anslysislist
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As analysis)
                _anslysislist = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    <DataContract()>
    Public Class components

        Private _primarynumber As Integer
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property primary_number As String
            Get
                Return _primarynumber
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _primarynumber = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _streetname As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property street_name As String
            Get
                Return _streetname
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _streetname = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _streetsufix As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property street_suffix As String
            Get
                Return _streetsufix
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _streetsufix = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _city_name As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property city_name As String
            Get
                Return _city_name
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _city_name = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _state_abbreviation As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property state_abbreviation As String
            Get
                Return _state_abbreviation
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _state_abbreviation = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _zipcode As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property zipcode As String
            Get
                Return _zipcode
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _zipcode = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _plus4_code As Integer
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property plus4_code As String
            Get
                Return _plus4_code
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _plus4_code = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _delivery_point As Integer
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property delivery_point As String
            Get
                Return _delivery_point
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _delivery_point = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _delivery_point_check_digit As Integer
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property delivery_point_check_digit As String
            Get
                Return _delivery_point_check_digit
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _delivery_point_check_digit = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    <DataContract()>
    Public Class metadata
        Private _record_type As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property record_type As String
            Get
                Return _record_type
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _record_type = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _zip_type As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property zip_type As String
            Get
                Return _zip_type
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _zip_type = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _county_fips As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property county_fips As String
            Get
                Return _county_fips
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _county_fips = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _county_name As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property county_name As String
            Get
                Return _county_name
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _county_name = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _carrier_route As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property carrier_route As String
            Get
                Return _carrier_route
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _carrier_route = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _congressional_district As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property congressional_district As String
            Get
                Return _congressional_district
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _congressional_district = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _rdi As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property rdi As String
            Get
                Return _rdi
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _rdi = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _elot_sequence As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property elot_sequence As String
            Get
                Return _elot_sequence
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _elot_sequence = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _elot_sort As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property elot_sort As String
            Get
                Return _elot_sort
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _elot_sort = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _latitude As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property latitude As String
            Get
                Return _latitude
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _latitude = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _longitude As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property longitude As String
            Get
                Return _longitude
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _longitude = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _precision As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property precision As String
            Get
                Return _precision
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _precision = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _time_zone As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property time_zone As String
            Get
                Return _time_zone
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _time_zone = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _utc_offset As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property utc_offset As String
            Get
                Return _utc_offset
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _utc_offset = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _dst As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property dst As String
            Get
                Return _dst
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _dst = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    <DataContract()>
    Public Class analysis
        Private _dpv_match_code As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property dpv_match_code As String
            Get
                Return _dpv_match_code
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _dpv_match_code = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _dpv_footnotes As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property dpv_footnotes As String
            Get
                Return _dpv_footnotes
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _dpv_footnotes = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _dpv_cmra As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property dpv_cmra As String
            Get
                Return _dpv_cmra
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _dpv_cmra = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _dpv_vacant As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property dpv_vacant As String
            Get
                Return _dpv_vacant
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _dpv_vacant = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _active As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property active As String
            Get
                Return _active
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _active = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _footnotes As String
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property footnotes As String
            Get
                Return _footnotes
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _footnotes = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

**Get the values from the json String:**

```
Dim output As String
output = objUSPSAPI.FormatJson(wsClient.DownloadString(inputUrl))  ' download json string from external source
Dim JsonDataobj = New List(Of JsonData)
Dim ser = New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(List(Of JsonData)))
Dim stream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output))
JsonDataobj = TryCast(ser.ReadObject(stream), List(Of JsonData))
If JsonDataobj IsNot Nothing AndAlso JsonDataobj.Count > 0 Then
    Dim Uspsdata As New DataTable
    Uspsdata.Columns.Add("primary_number", GetType(System.String))
    Uspsdata.Columns.Add("street_name", GetType(System.String))
    Uspsdata.Columns.Add("street_suffix", GetType(System.String))
    Uspsdata.Columns.Add("city_name", GetType(System.String))
    Uspsdata.Columns.Add("state_abbreviation", GetType(System.String))
    Uspsdata.Columns.Add("zipcode", GetType(System.String))
    Uspsdata.Columns.Add("plus4_code", GetType(System.String))
    Uspsdata.Columns.Add("delivery_point", GetType(System.String))
    Uspsdata.Columns.Add("delivery_point_check_digit", GetType(System.String))
    Dim dr As DataRow
    For Each objaddress As JsonData In JsonDataobj
        If Not objaddress.components Is Nothing Then
            dr = Uspsdata.NewRow
            dr("primary_number") = objaddress.components.primary_number.ToString()
            dr("street_name") = objaddress.components.street_name.ToString()
            dr("street_suffix") = objaddress.components.street_suffix.ToString()
            dr("city_name") = objaddress.components.city_name.ToString()
            dr("state_abbreviation") = objaddress.components.state_abbreviation.ToString()
            dr("zipcode") = objaddress.components.zipcode.ToString()
            dr("plus4_code") = objaddress.components.plus4_code.ToString()
            dr("delivery_point") = objaddress.components.delivery_point.ToString()
            dr("delivery_point_check_digit") = objaddress.components.delivery_point_check_digit.ToString()
            Uspsdata.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If
    Next
```